# Effect of `\label` on caption position in new environment

Tags: formatting, environments, minipage

I use a [new environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/467570/formatting-of-new-environment-based-on-minipage-and-sidecaption) and have tried to refer to it using the `\label`-`\ref`commands. I'm running into the problem that the `\label` command affects the vertical position of the caption.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% caption for new environment
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycaption}[1]{%
 \strictpagecheck\marginpar{\setlength{\parindent}{1.0em}\small
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading {\textbf{Caption \themynewcount:}} #1}%
}
\makeatother

%%% new environment
\newcounter{mynewcount}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\themynewcount}{\thechapter.\arabic{mynewcount}}   

\newenvironment{mynewenv}[1]{%
 \refstepcounter{mynewcount}%
 \vspace{2\abovedisplayskip}%
 \mycaption{#1}%
 \vspace{-\abovedisplayskip} 
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
 }{\end{minipage}\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{mynewenv}{Caption}
\label{test} % <<< label
\lipsum[2]
\end{mynewenv}
\ref{test} % <<< refer to label
\end{document}
```

Without the `\label` and `\ref` commands, the caption is properly aligned with the top of the contents of the environment:

[image]

With them, however, the caption is shifted up:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning:** since your code uses `marginpar` it could not be well aligned with the mini page.

You could change the `mynewenv` environment definition to have an optional argument to be used within `\label`, as shown below:

```
\newenvironment{mynewenv}[2][]{% <-- here
 \refstepcounter{mynewcount}%
 \vspace{2\abovedisplayskip}%
 \mycaption{#2}\label{#1}%       <-- here
 \vspace{-\abovedisplayskip} 
 \noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
 }{\end{minipage}\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

Then, you simply pass the `label` as option, like:

```
\begin{mynewenv}[test]{Caption}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mynewenv}
As we can see in \ref{test}...
```

Or without the option (but in this case, some warning could happens if using multiple times):

```
\begin{mynewenv}{Caption}
\lipsum[2]
\end{mynewenv}
```

[image]

Comment: If the optional argument is not used, `\label{}` will occur, which is no problem, but awful, but you will get `multiply defined labels` warnings when using the environment twice or more times without setting the optional argument.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, ow, that is true. Some use of `nextchar` could help.

Comment: Easier: Use `xparse` and `\NewDocumentEnvironment{mynewenv}{o+m}{... \IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}} ... rest as given, for example)}{\end{minipage}}`

Comment: Actually, the optional argument is the better way, since the label should occur after the `\mycaption` and not in the environment body, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am having problem to align to mini page because the depth, I think.

Comment: Thanks, this solves my problem. As you noted in your warning, I've since discovered a few cases in which the caption is not well aligned with the top of the environment's contents. As you point to the `\marginpar` as the culprit, I should point out that I'm not wedded to it. I just use it because this is something I'm already using in my `memoir` document. Do you have any suggestions for how to fix the alignment problem?